# How to keep the current input after clicking submit button in Laravel filter?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filters

I am trying to get the old input after cilcking submit button using get method in laravel filter?
in my view blade

```html
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'/jobseekers','method'=>'GET', 'class'=>'form', 'id'=>'search_data']) !!}        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
<input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Name" value="{{ Session::get('fullname') }}" class="form-control"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4"><button class="btn btn-flat btn-primary">Search</button>
</div>{!! Form::close() !!}
```

and in my controller

```
           $result = null;
        if(count($request->all())!=0){  
            if ($request->has('sub_search')) {
                $jobseekers = Jobseeker::Subsearch($request)->paginate(10); 
                dd($applicant_information);
            }else{
                $result=Jobseeker::Search($request)->paginate(10);  
              //  dd($orders);
            } 
        }
        else{
            $jobseekers = Jobseeker::with('calllogs')->orderBy('jobseekers.created_at','DESC')->paginate(16);
        }       
       return view('backend.jobseekers.index',compact('jobseekers','result'));
```

I cant get the old input value in my view file after clicking submit button.Please guide me, how to do it?

Comment: to keep the old inputs you should use withInput() method chained to return view: 
return view('backend.jobseekers.index',compact('jobseekers','result'))->withInput();

Comment: it give me the error like "Undefined offset: 0
" any idea ? sir

Comment: I don't know where that comes since I dont know the implémentations of methods Search and Subsearch. but generally this errors occurs when you try to access empty array, or an array that don't have a '0' key .
Also you try to access $request->has('sub_search') but there is no sub_search field in your form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Name" value="{{ request()->input('fullname') }}" class="form-control"/>
```

Comment: as @Mehrud mentioned : you can use `{{old("fullname")}}`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the very simple to use Laravel helper function which is `old("fullname")`